# Cayley Transform for all reductive groups a.k.a an algebraic logarithm

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Is it true that for every reductive algebraic $G$ over ${\mathbb C}$ with a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of the identity in $G$ and an algebraic function (in a sense of algebraic geometry) $L: U\to \mathfrak g$ which satisfies the following properties of logarithm:

(1) $L$ is $G$-equivariant with respect to the $G$-action on $G$ by conjugation and the Adjoint $G$-action on $\mathfrak g,$
(2) $L(e)=0,$
(3) $dL$ is an isomorphism at $e$,
(4) For some maximal torus $T$ in $G$, $L(T\cap U)$ lies in the Lie algebra of $T.$

For $G=GL(n,\mathbb C)$, the embedding $L:GL(n,\mathbb C)\to gl(n,\mathbb C)$ works.
For $G=SO(n,\mathbb C)$, the Cayley Transform works: $L(A)= (I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$.
Cayley transform has a version for symplectic matrices as well.

Is there a construction which works for all $G$? If not, are there known ad hoc constructions for exceptional groups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bardsley and Richardson (Etale slices for algebraic transformation groups in characteristic p.
Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 51 (1985), no. 2, 295–317) give a construction which seems to do what you want. It gives less than a "Cayley map" as in Borovoi's answer.

Let $G$ be connected and semisimple over a field of char. 0.
Bardsley and Richardson construct a mapping $G \to \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ with 
nice properties (which I'll indicate below).

Note that we may as well suppose that $G$ is of adjoint type -- indeed,
if the problem is solved already for the adjoint group $G_{\operatorname{ad}}$,
just take the composite
$$G \to G_{\operatorname{ad}} \to \operatorname{Lie}(G).$$

Now, since the characteristic of $k$ is zero and $G$ is of adjoint type, the adjoint representation
$V = \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ is a faithful representation of $G$ for which the
trace form
defined by $\kappa(X,Y) = \operatorname{tr}(X \circ Y)$ -- a non-degenerate
form on $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$-- remains non-degenerate on the image
$\operatorname{ad}(\operatorname{Lie}(G)) \simeq \operatorname{Lie}(G) \subset \mathfrak{gl}(V)$.

Writing $M$ for the orthogonal complement $M=\operatorname{ad}(\operatorname{Lie}(G))^\perp$ with respect to the form $\kappa$,
we have
$$\mathfrak{gl}(V) = M \oplus \operatorname{ad}(\operatorname{Lie}(G))$$
as $G$-representations.
Write $\pi:\mathfrak{gl}(V) \to \operatorname{ad}(\operatorname{Lie}(G))$ for
the projection on the second factor.

Since $G$ is semisimple, $\operatorname{ad}(\operatorname{Lie}(G)) \subset
\mathfrak{sl}(V)$ so that the identity mapping $I$ satisfies
$\kappa(I,\operatorname{ad}X) = \operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{ad}X)  = 0$ 
for each $X \in \operatorname{Lie}(G)$. Thus $I \in M$.

Write $\lambda$ for the composite mapping
$$G \to \operatorname{GL}(V) \subset \mathfrak{gl}(V) \xrightarrow{\pi} \operatorname{ad}(
\operatorname{Lie}(G))$$.

Since $I \in M$, evidentally $\lambda(1) = 0$. Since $\pi$ is a $G$-module
homomorphism, $\lambda$ is $G$-equivariant.
Moreover, by construction $d\lambda_1$ is the identity mapping. Finally, by $G$-equivariance
the image under $\lambda$ of a maximal torus $T$ is contained in the $T$-fixed
points of $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$, i.e. in $\operatorname{Lie}(T)$.

This verifies the stipulated conditions (1),(2),(3) and (4).

Note that Barsdsley and Richardson go on to show that the restriction of $\lambda$
to the unipotent variety $\mathcal{U} \subset G$ defines a $G$-equivariant isomorphism
$\mathcal{U} \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathcal{N}$ where $\mathcal{N} \subset \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ is the nilpotent variety.

Moreover, by Luna's theorem (a proof valid in positive characteristic is given in Bardsley and Richardson's paper) there are $G$-invariant open subset $U \subset G$ and $U' \subset \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ with $1 \in U$ and $0 \in U'$ such that $\lambda_{\mid U}$ defines a surjective
etale mapping $U \to U'$. So $\lambda$ need not be birational, but it is fairly nice.

Note that Barsdley and Richardson actually formulate the above construction more generally
using representations $V$ of $G$ which are "nice enough" (among other things, the restriction of the traceform on $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ to the image of $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$ must be non-degenerate), and under suitable assumptions (very roughly: the characteristic should be good for $G$) their construction gives "explicit" Springer isomorphisms $\mathcal{U} \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathcal{N}$ in characteristic $p>0$.

Comment: There's also a paper by Kostant and Michor studying this composite map.

Comment: Can we get the classical Cayley map for SO_n from a version of this construction?

Comment: @Mikhail: I don't know the answer to that question. I'm a bit skeptical, though. The "natural candidate" for $G=SO(V)$ is to apply the construction for the natural representation $V$. In that case, unless I'm making a silly back-of-the-envelope goof, the map seems to be given by the rule $X \mapsto \dfrac{X^2-1}{2X}$, which is similar to the Cayley map but not the same. This map seems not to be birational...

Comment: @Allen: Thanks -- I hadn't seen that paper of Kostant and Michor.

Answer (score 21):

A *Cayley map* is a  $G$-equivariant birational isomorphism  $\lambda: G\to \mathfrak{g}$ (which does not have to exist).
A connected linear algebraic group $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is called a *Cayley group* if it admits a Cayley map,
and it is called a *stably Cayley group* if $G\times (\mathbb{G}_m)^n$ is a Cayley group for some $n=0,1,2,\dots$.
These notions were introduced in the paper [Cayley groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409004) by Lemire, Popov and Reichstein.
As usual, the "stable" question is easier than the original one.

The authors classified Cayley and stably Cayley simple groups.
They proved the following result:

> **Theorem.** The stably Cayley simple groups over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic 0 are the following:
>   $SL_2$, $SL_3$, $SO_n$, $Sp_{2n}$, $PGL_n$, and $G_2$. All these groups are Cayley, except $G_2$.
>   The group $G_2$ is not Cayley (V. A. Iskovskikh),
>   but $G_2\times (\mathbb{G}_m)^2$ is Cayley.

Note that the question whether $G_2\times \mathbb{G}_m$ is Cayley is open.
Note also that all the groups of types $E_6$, $E_7$, $E_8$ and $F_4$ are  not stably Cayley, hence they are not Cayley.
In addition, the groups $SL_2$ and $SL_3$ are Cayley, while $SL_4$, $SL_5$, $SL_6$ and so on are not stably Cayley, hence they are not Cayley.

EDIT: After I answered the question in 2012, new papers on Cayley groups appeared: 
[Stably Cayley groups in characteristic zero](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1329), where, in particular, stably Cayley *simple* groups over an arbitrary field of characteristic 0 are classified;
[Stably Cayley semisimple groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5774), where stably Cayley *semisimple* groups over an arbitrary field of characteristic 0 are classified;
[Real reductive Cayley groups of rank 1 and 2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.1065), where for all reductive $\mathbb R$-groups of rank 1 and 2 we determine whether they are Cayley (not just stably Cayley) or not.

Concerning the paper "Stably Cayley semisimple groups", note that a product of stably Cayley simple groups is clearly a stably Cayley semisimple group, but it is not true that any stably Cayley semisimple group is a product of stably Cayley simple groups. Indeed, ${SO}_4$ is a Cayley group (this was proved by Cayley), hence it is a stably Cayley group, but it is not simple and not a product of simple groups, hence it is not a product of simple stably Cayley groups. However, it was proved in this paper that any stably Cayley semisimple group $G$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic 0 can be written as
$$ G=G_1\times_k\dots\times_k G_s\,,$$ 
where each $G_i$ is either a stably Cayley *simple group* (from the above theorem), or the stably Cayley *semisimple group* ${SO}_4$.

In the paper "Real reductive Cayley groups of rank 1 and 2" we show, in particular, that 
over $\mathbb R$ the group $SU_3$ is Cayley, while $SL_{3,\mathbb R}$ is not Cayley. Note that both groups are stably Cayley because all reductive groups of absolute rank  $\le 2$ over a field of characteristic 0 are stably Cayley.